# How to install Mesa 20.1-devel Git on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, mesa

Trying to run Cyberpunk 2077 on Ubuntu 20.04, the game requires `4.5 Mesa 21.0.0-devel (git-04c7fce799)` How can I install that driver on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```